# Integrating Google+ into Rails app (execute not working)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, google-plus

I am trying to display data from Google+ by adapting this to rails https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client I created a rails app, made a few tweaks to get oauth working with the client_secret.json, but when the request executes, nothing displays.

welcome_controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
def index

require 'google/api_client'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
require 'google/api_client/auth/installed_app'

$credentials = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load

# Initialize the client.
$authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
:authorization_uri => $credentials.authorization_uri,
:token_credential_uri => $credentials.token_credential_uri,
:client_id => $credentials.client_id,
:client_secret => $credentials.client_secret,
:redirect_uri => $credentials.redirect_uris.first,
:scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login')

@client = Google::APIClient.new(
:application_name => 'X',
:application_version => 'X'
)

# Initialize Google+ API. Note this will make a request to the
# discovery service every time, so be sure to use serialization
# in your production code. Check the samples for more details.
@plus = @client.discovered_api( "plus", "v1" )

# Make an API call.
@google_plus_info = @client.execute(
:api_method => @plus.activities.list,
:parameters => {'collection' => 'public', 'userId' => 'my_num_here'}
)

#puts @google_plus_info.data  #tried this
render plain: "test: #{@google_plus_info.data}" #tried this too, just returns the call name
end
end
```

Anyone know why I'm getting it in this case, according to the API (i thought) this was a public call? NOTE: I changed this post in response to suggestions to show my current state of work.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try replacing `$authorization.execute` with `plus.execute`</strike>

Take a look at https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client-samples/tree/master/googleplus

Here's a snippet from my working code:

```
@client = Google::APIClient.new(
  :application_name => 'X',
  :application_version => 'X'
)
@client.authorization.update_token!(:access_token => 'X', :refresh_token => 'X')
@plus = @client.discovered_api( "plus", "v1" )
@google_plus_info = @client.execute(
  :api_method => @plus.people.get,
  :parameters => {'collection' => 'public', 'userId' => 'me'}
)
```

Comment: @Rilcon42 - you're not putting in the access_token information in... see my added example and also the link to Google's example

Comment: But I am providing a userID, and the method call is public, so I shouldnt need an auth token, but im still not returning data.